# Is it possible to create storage in for an n element array where the elements are tuples?

Tags: ocaml

I'm making a class that is supposed to be able to store a 20 element array with each element being a tuple of four predefined types. Another catch is, I can't use parameters.

I can't find good online sources for this and the material provided from my university is honestly insufficient. I'm preparing for an exam and I'm stumped when it comes to objects in OCaml.

I was thinking of doing something like

```
val mutable arr = Array.make 20 (input 20 values)
```

but this seems too simplistic and inefficient to be a correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields of a class can have any type. This certainly includes an array type. Arrays, in turn, can contain any type, which includes tuples.

Any given mutable field and any given array is, of course, restricted to always contain values of the same type. This is what it means to have "strong" typing.

OCaml is a high level language, so there's no need (or opportunity, really) to be concerned with too many details of representation. If you want a class with a field like you say, your proposted type sounds perfectly fine.

```
type mytuple = int * float * char

class myclass = object
  val mutable myfield : mytuple array = [||]
end
```

You can find good documentation on OCaml at [realworldocaml.org](http://realworldocaml.org/). There are more resources listed at [ocaml.org](http://ocaml.org/).

Comment: Why use something like val mutable list = ([ ]:int list) then in the first place? Does it make a difference?

Thank you for the sources.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking exactly. Lists and arrays are different and are best for different things. For example, adding an element to the front of a list takes constant time, but linear time for an array. Accessing an arbitrary element takes constant time for an array but linear time for a list.

Comment: My point is,wouldnt something like val mutable myfield : int list = [ ] achieve the same thing? Im trying to find some consistency with the syntax.

Comment: OCaml will infer types, so you don't need to specify the type at all. But when initializing with an empty value (array or list) I like to specify the type, since the inferred type will still be polymorphic at that point. Either the value or the variable can be annotated with a type, or both.